# How to convert string "2011-11-29 12:34:25" to date in "dd-MM-yyyy" format in JAVA

Tags: java, string, date, format

I am trying to convert date which is in string and got format of "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" to "dd-MM-yyyy".

I have implmented following code but its giving :  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException

```
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
        Date date = new Date(values);
        String mydate = dateFormat.format(date);
```

Comment: what line is throwing the exception?

Comment: what is values.And are u sure simpleDateformatter is throwing exception

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java string to date conversion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4216745/java-string-to-date-conversion)

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleTextFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First you have to parse the string representation of your date-time into a Date object.

```
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
Date date = (Date)formatter.parse("2011-11-29 12:34:25");
```

Then you format the Date object back into a String in your preferred format.

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
String mydate = dateFormat.format(date);
```

Comment: Uhm... No... He asked for dd-MM-yyyy.

Answer (score 2):

You need to parse the date, using another `SimpleDateFormat`

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat2 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
Date date = dateFormat2.parse(values);
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
String mydate = dateFormat.format(date);
```

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

```
LocalDateTime.parse( 
    "2011-11-29 12:34:25".replace( " " , "T " ) 
).format (
    DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd-MM-uuuu" )
)
```

> 29-11-2011

## Using java.time

The modern approach uses the java.time classes rather than the troublesome legacy classes.

## ISO 8601

Your input string of “2011-11-29 12:34:25” has a format nearly that of the ISO 8601 standard. To fully comply, replace the SPACE in the middle with a `T`.

```
String input = "2011-11-29 12:34:25".replace( " " , "T " );
```

Without any indication of time zone or offset-from-UTC, we parse as a `LocalDateTime`.

```
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse( input ) ;
```

You want the date-only value, so extract a `LocalDate`. The [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone.

```
LocalDate ld = ldt.toLocalDate() ;
```

To generate a string in your desired format, you specify a custom formatting pattern.

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd-MM-uuuu" );
String output = ld.format( f );
```

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

The `IllegalArgumentException` probably occurs when program trying to construct `Date` object

What's the value ?

Following code snippet runs correctly.

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
Date date = new Date();
String mydate = dateFormat.format(date);

System.out.println(mydate);
```

Output :

*29/11/2011*

Answer (score 0):

The constructor to `Date` takes a long representing the time in milliseconds. You need to use another `SimpleDateFormat` instance to parse your input string into a timestamp first.

Answer (score 0):

try this way

```
String mydate = "2011-11-29 12:34:25"
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
Date date = null;

try{
   date = sdf.parse(mydate);
   SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
   String mydate = dateFormat.format(date);
}catch(Exception ex){
   // handle exception
}
```